# Clarification on the hierarchy of the command Interface

Tags: java

In the following program in the class Parent the class Child implements MyInterface. Is that the reason why obj1 (Parent) instanceof MyInterface is false, while obj2 (Child) instanceof MyInterace is true?

```
    class InstanceofDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parent obj1 = new Parent();
        Parent obj2 = new Child();

        System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Parent: "
            + (obj1 instanceof Parent));
        System.out.println("obj1 instanceof Child: "
            + (obj1 instanceof Child));
        System.out.println("obj1 instanceof MyInterface: "
            + (obj1 instanceof MyInterface));
        System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Parent: "
            + (obj2 instanceof Parent));
        System.out.println("obj2 instanceof Child: "
            + (obj2 instanceof Child));
        System.out.println("obj2 instanceof MyInterface: "
            + (obj2 instanceof MyInterface));
    }


}

class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent implements MyInterface {}
interface MyInterface {}
```

Gives the following output:

```
obj1 instanceof Parent: true
obj1 instanceof Child: false
obj1 instanceof MyInterface: false
obj2 instanceof Parent: true
obj2 instanceof Child: true
obj2 instanceof MyInterface: true
```

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. If Parent does not implement MyInterface, the instanceof statement will return false.

Answer (score 0):

because just your `Child` class implement `MyInterface`, so if you want an instance of your `Parent` class be a instance of your your `MyInterface` interface you have to implement `MyInterface` in your `Parent` class. Something like this :

```
class Parent implements MyInterface{}
class Child extends Parent {}
interface MyInterface {}
```

this will give this output:

```
obj1 instanceof Parent: true
obj1 instanceof Child: false
obj1 instanceof MyInterface: true
obj2 instanceof Parent: true
obj2 instanceof Child: true
obj2 instanceof MyInterface: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple in terms of real world objects. Map the below example with given java objects.
I have the below classes and interface:

```
class HumanBeing{}
interface Teachable{}
class Teacher extends HumanBeing implements Teachable{}
```

**Real World Example:**

The above class and interface definitions can be interpreted like below:

- "Human Being" exists in the world
- All "Teacher" are Human Being who is "Teachable"

Which means to become a Teacher one must be a HumanBeing.
Now say for example Gopal is just "Human Being" and Varma is "Teacher"

```
HumanBeing gopal = new HumanBeing();
HumanBeing varma = new Teacher();
```

Now evaluate the below questions, you will easily understand the concept:

- is Gopal Human Being? YES
- is Gopal Teachable? NO
- is Gopal Teacher? NO
- is Varma Human Being? YES, because he is Teacher (all teacher are human being)
- is Varma Teachable? YES
- is Varma Teacher? YES